# Java: Can't assign MyClass to Object type?

Tags: java, android, class, object, assign

So I'm doing an Android app, and I've added the a tag to a view through:

```
view.setTag(1,myClass);
```

Now I want to get that tag through this:

```
myClass = view.getTag(1);
```

But it says:

> Incopatible types
>
> Required: MyClass
>
> Found: java.lang.Object

Yes, I've declared myClass before...

So, how can I make MyClass be able to be "created" or "assigned" from an Object? Such as Strings and Integers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cast it? `myClass = (MyClassType) view.getTag(1);`

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast it.

```
myClass = (MyClass) view.getTag(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28int%29) the return type of `getTag(int i)` is `Object`. One option is to cast the returned object to the type that you expect.

```
Object obj = view.getTag(1);

if(obj instanceOf MyClass){
    MyClass myClass = (MyClass) obj;
}
```

However,if you only need to store the class type, the following is a little more interesting:

```
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();

view.setTag(1, myInstance);

Class type = view.getTag(1).getClass();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't even know how I got this far without knowing how to cast.